# java jar arguments for swing application

Tags: java, jar, command-line-arguments

I am working on a java swing application which currently allows a user to import one or more files to be processed.

This is done right now by executing the jar using

`java -jar [jarname] [filename 1] [filename 2] ... [filename N]`.

I am tasked with to change the behaviour so as to keep it working in this current mode and add another mode of execution by adding an option parameter:

`java -jar [jarname] [filename 1] -o [option]`.

In the second mode, I need to make sure that the arguments contain a single filename argument with a single option flag followed by a single option argument. The option will be used to process the file. Alternatively, if the jar is executed in the first mode using only one file, there is a menu option in the application that the user should be able to use to process the file with the required option.

I am looking for ideas/tips to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  What exactly is giving you trouble?

Comment: How are you reading the arguments? Using `public void main(String[] args)` and using args as in the input?  Just check to see if `-o` appears in args, and treat the value after that as the option to set

Comment: Hint: what happens if you have a file named `-o`?

Comment: This is my argument parsing logic so far

Comment: `if (args.length > 0) {
 if (args.length == 3) {
  // check if the second argument is the filter option "-o"
  if (args[1].compareTo("-o") == 0) {
   String option = args[2].toLowerCase();
   String[] fileName = new String[1];
   fileName[0] = args[0];
   mode2(fileName);
   mode2.option(option);
  } 
  else {
   mode1();
  }
    } else {
  mode1();
    }
} `